# New-AzureRmRoleAssignment : Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: azure-runbook

Unable to assign role to user using `New-AzureRmRoleAssignment` command. When I run the above command its thronging an error as follows .

```
New-AzureRmRoleAssignment : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Can any one help to resole the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To assign role to user successfully in the runbook, follow the steps below.

**Note** : The `New-AzureRmRoleAssignment` you used belongs to the old `AzureRM`, it was deprecated and will not be updated anymore. In my sample, I use the new [`Az`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-3.8.0) command [`New-AzRoleAssignment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.Resources/New-azRoleAssignment?view=azps-4.2.0), I also recommend you to use it.

1.Navigate to the subscription in the portal(you need to be `Owner/User Access Administrator` in the subscription) -> add the service principal of your automation RunAs account as an `Owner/User Access Administrator`(by default it will be added as `Contributor` when it was created, but `Contributor` have no permission to run `New-AzRoleAssignment`).

[image]

2.Navigate to the `Azure Active Directory` in the portal -> `App registrations` -> find the AD App of your RunAs Account and add the `Directory.Read.All` *application* permission in `Azure Active Directory Graph`(*Not Microsoft Graph*) like below, don't forget to click the `Grant admin consent for xxx` button at last(you need to be the admin role in your AAD tenant). The permission may take about 30 min to take effect.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

3.Navigate to the automation account in the portal -> `Modules` -> make sure you have installed the `Az.Accounts`, `Az.Resources` modules, if not, go to `Browse Gallery`, search for the names, and install them.

[image]

4.Then in the runbook, use the script below, it works fine on my side. In my sample, I add the user as a `Reader` in the resource group `joyRG`, you can change it, it depends on your requirement.

```
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try
{
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

    "Logging in to Azure..."
    Connect-AzAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
}
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}

$user = Get-AzADUser -UserPrincipalName joyw2@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com
New-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId $user.id -ResourceGroupName joyRG -RoleDefinitionName Reader
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you JOY its working fine. Can you please explain me why we need to use Connect-AzAccount command here.

Comment: @venkatesh When we use the `Az` commands, we always need to `Connect-AzAccount` first.